# How fast can I poll with AJAX?

Tags: performance, ajax

Let's say I'm updating some data on a page using Ajax. I need to call it on a timer so if a user sits on the page it will keep updating. What's a reasonable rate to poll at to try and maintain a "real-time" feel without running up the client's CPU usage or impeding them in some other noticeable way?

Comment: I'd say the problem isn't the clients CPU, it's the combined load from all the clients polling on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to maintain that level of a real time feel, I would strongly suggest that you look into [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).  Comet -- also known as Reverse Ajax -- involves the client JavaScript opening a connection to the server and the server keeping that connection open until it's ready to send a response/update to the client.

This is used a lot in live chat applications, and there are [Chat Demos](http://blog.conversionsupport.com/2010/12/channelapi-comet-chat-demo-on-google.html) and other [Comet Demos](http://cometdaily.com/) that demonstrate the concept.

If you poll any more often than about 10 seconds, you will waste bandwidth and CPU cycles.  The overhead of opening and closing a connection and the load on your server would be intense.

Comment: Yeah, I guess another question could be the merit or value of polling vs comet vs websockets.

Comment: @Ryan - Comet is more mainstream yet is a hackjob.  It does work well with the Jetty Web Server and Dojo Cometd.  Websockets is only available in Chrome that I know of.